# General expression for hypergeometric function ${}_1F{}_1(p, 1, x)$ when p is an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series

> I am interested in the general expression for the function  ${}_1F{}_1(p, 1, x)$ when p is an integer.

It seems, if I am to believe mathematica that its values are for $p=0,1,2…$

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & e^x \\
 2 & e^x (x+1) \\
 3 & e^x \left(\frac{x^2}{2}+2 x+1\right) \\
 4 & e^x \left(\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+3 x+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
I would be interested in quoting the general expression for an arbitrary $p$.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Conjuncture

$${}_1F_1(p+1,1,x)=e^{x}L_p(-x)=e^x\sum_{k=0}^p\frac{x^k}{k!}{p \choose k}$$

Where $L_p$ is the [Laguerre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials)

I have not got any proof for the above equality. I'll try it later.

Comment: Thanks so much! Its related to the spin of galaxies in large scales structures as it happens

Comment: @chris, Thanks. I am sorry for my incomplete answer, though.

Comment: More generally its `If[p > 0, Exp[x] LaguerreL[p - 1, -x],
 LaguerreL[-p, x]]` for negative p to work as well.

Comment: Would you know what `Hypergeometric1F1[p, 2, x]` could be? Its the only other one I need :-)

Comment: @chris, I have no idea how to evaluate that.

Comment: Ok never mind! What motivated the conjecture?

Comment: @chris, Mathematica uses Laguerrel function to represent Hypergeometric functions.

Comment: it seems the answer is `Sum[(-x)^k/k!/(k + 1) Binomial[p, k], {k, 0, p}]==Hypergeometric1F1[-p, 2, x]`